# Audit logging in multiple microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have 4 micro-services and web-app to access REST calls. I want to log the operations user performing for any backend call. I am thinking to implement audit-log micro-service which has just one DB table and just one RESTful operation. Every time user performs any operation, that micro-service will call RESTFul API of audit-log.

Do you think this approach is better or is there any other best practices or solution?

I implemented micro-service.

I am using java 8, JPA, Spring Framework, Mongo DB

I expect good design and good practice to follow in my code

Answer (score 1):

Solution strongly depends on that what data do you want to collect. If you want to collect only calls statistics, ready-made solutions should suit you (soft like Jeager or Zipkin). If you don't want to use ready-made solution MQ will be better choice than REST API.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need Hibernate Envers. if you are looking for auditing on crud operation look into Envers.
https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/